# Simple foreach loop iteration

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a really basic problem. I want to iterate through a multidimensional-array. Suppose I want to add an if statement to check values without breaking the foreach loop... my purpose is to get an array of specific values

```
$foo =  [
     'one'=> [
             'id'=>1,
             'name'=>'32dsfd23'
             ],

    'two' => [
             'id'=>1,
             'name'=>'322e3'
             ],
    ];

    function new_func($arr){

        $data=[];
        foreach($arr as $val) {

                foreach($val as $key =>$foofoo) {
                    if(array_key_exists('id',$val)){
                    $data['new_arr']=$foofoo;
                }
                }

        }
        return $data;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(new_func($foo));
    echo "</pre>";
```

The result is : 
`Array
(
    [new_arr] => 322e3
)`

And I want to get something like this :
    `Array
(
    [new_arr] 
                 [0]=> 32dsfd23,
                 [1]=> 322e3,
)`

Comment: $data['new_arr'][]=$foofoo;  2 dimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push the new elements in the array. Now you overwrite them.

```
$foo =  [
     'one'=> [
         'id'=>1,
         'name'=>'32dsfd23'
         ],

    'two' => [
         'id'=>1,
         'name'=>'322e3'
         ],
    ];

    function new_func($arr){

        $data=[];
        foreach($arr as $val) {
            foreach($val as $key =>$foofoo) {
                if(array_key_exists('id',$val)) {

                    $data['new_arr'][] = $foofoo;

                }
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(new_func($foo));
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do
`$data['new_arr']=$foofoo;`
you're overwriting the value in your $data['new_arr'].

You need to change that to `$data['new_arr'][]=$foofoo;` which will insert the value in that array.